# What happened to StringDecoder in Dart?

Tags: dart

I opened an old Dart project, and I get a warning about `StringDecoder` being undefined. How do I update my code? What do I use instead of `StringDecoder` ?

Example code:

```dart
response.transform(new StringDecoder()).toList().then((list) {
  print('$_client results...');
  print('${list.join()}');
  client.close();
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `StringEncoder` and `StringDecoder` classes have been removed from
dart:io.

Instead, import `dart:convert` and use the decoders of the Encodings.

Examples:

`new StringDecoder()` -> `utf8.decoder`

`new StringDecoder(encoding)` -> `encoding.decoder`

`new StringEncoder()` -> `utf8.encoder`

Comment: Sorry if I missed something, but why did you ask and answer(within the same minute) your own question?

Comment: @JamesBruckner to do the community a service for those who will also run into this problem.

Comment: @JamesBruckner - See this for more: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: @SethLadd If you have time, please update the docs at places like here: https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-io-http so that people don't continue to make this mistake, like I just did.

Comment: @plowman thanks, we're updating them now in anticipation for 1.0. Don't hesitate to file doc bugs at dartbug.com/new